# How to run python web pages with Apache?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, python

Currently our web server is **LAMP** based,

but I need to install **trac**, which is written by python,

how can **Apache** support **python** requests?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want [`mod_wsgi`](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracModWSGI) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the guide here: http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall